# editing built.xml in windows for tomcat's path location

Tags: tomcat, struts

I am using Windows, trying to set the path of my Tomcat to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22` in `built.xml`.
Please tell me how to specify.

```xml
<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath>

        <path location="${appserver.home}/server/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Add a property to your build.xml
2. Run ant with a parameter

   ant -Dappserver.home="c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22" reload